# use jersey 2.x with CDI without declare service into AbstractBinder

Tags: jboss, jersey, cdi

I have a simple webapp work well with jersey 2.6, jboss 5.0.0. 
The approach of declaring all my inject class ( services) into a AbstractBinder isn't  elegancy.

So I want use CDI injection  to manage all the life cycle bean management. I've seen it's possible with use @manageBean instead @ScopeResquest. I tried it with this error :

```
> javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 3 exceptions. 
> They are:
> 1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at
> Injectee(requiredType=ServiceExemple,parent=RestService,qualifiers={}),position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,2072559159)
> 2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of fr.xx.xx.rest.RestService  errors were
> found
> 3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on fr.xx.xx.rest.RestService
> 
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:392)
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
>   org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
>   org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

My config pom :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>


             <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-weld2-se</artifactId>
                <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x</artifactId>
               <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>RESTfulExample</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
         <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<!--        <init-param> -->
<!--            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> -->
<!--            <param-value>fr.xx.xx.rest</param-value> -->
<!--       </init-param> -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>fr.xx.xx.ApplicationRest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.beanValidation.disable.validateOnExecutableCheck.server</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

           <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.beanValidation.enableOutputValidationErrorEntity.server</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

my class application path :

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationRest extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationRest() {
        // Register resources and providers using package-scanning.
        packages("fr.xx.xx.rest");
        packages("org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs");

        register( JacksonFeature.class );
        register(org.glassfish.jersey.server.validation.ValidationFeature.class);
       // register(new ApplicationBinder()); => don't want use it
```

My simple service class :

```
@Default
public class ServiceExemple {
...
```

and to finish my resources class :

```
@Path("/service")
@ManagedBean
public class RestService {
  @Inject private ServiceExemple service;

...
```

I've add an empty bean.xml in my WEB-INF

Thanks for your help

Comment: Err JBoss 5.0? Are you sure?

Comment: yes Jboss 5.0.0 GA

Comment: If you want automatic service discovery you may want to use the hk2-metadata-generator (https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b36/inhabitant-generator.html) combined with a Populator (https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b36/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Populator.html). You can get the Populator for a ServiceLocator by getting the DynamicConfigurationService (https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b36/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/DynamicConfigurationService.html) which every ServiceLocator has and using the getPopulator method

Comment: @jwells131313 you seems to know this domain. Could you share some sample code. It will help thousands of people out there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all injected resources(beans) **and Jersey Endpoint class(point of injection)**  must be CDI-Aware. It must be detecteable by CDI. We can use bean-discovery-mode="all" - then CDI scan ALL classes  or 
bean-discovery-mode="annotated" and MARK our class with PROPER annotation: from here : [Bean defining annotations](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#default_bean_discovery). I prefer@Dependent or @RequestScoped

Then we must use Jersey Extension

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>{version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

`

to connect CDI with HK2 discovery mechanism.
Here is  [Official oracle Guideline](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced004.htm)